# Get JTable cell value with rowInModel Or rowInTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Which is correct for getting a cell value from a table:

```
int rowInTable = table.getSelectedRow();
int rowInModel = table.convertRowIndexToModel(rowInTable);


Object id = this.getValueAt(rowInModel,1);
```

Or:

```
Object id = this.getValueAt(rowInTable,1);
```

I get `id` in my model Class.

Comment: Neither suggestion is completely correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get id in my model Class.

Neither of your suggestions are correct. You are attempting to get the ID which appears to be column 1 of your TableModel. You have made an assumption that the columns of the table cannot be reordered which is not a good assumption to make since the default behaviour of a table allows the user to reorder columns.

You need to understand the difference between the "View" and the "Model".

```
int rowInTable = table.getSelectedRow();
int rowInModel = table.convertRowIndexToModel(rowInTable);
```

To get the value from the "View" (ie JTable) you would use:

```
Object id = this.getValueAt(rowInTable, table.convertColumnIndexToView(1));
```

To get the value from the "Model" you would use:

```
Object id = this.getModel().getValueAt(rowInModel, 1);
```

Both pieces of code will return the same value. In either case one index will need to be converted.

Answer (score 4):

This is the "correct" one.

```
int rowInTable = table.getSelectedRow();
int rowInModel = table.convertRowIndexToModel(rowInTable);
Object id = this.getValueAt(rowInModel,1);
```

This is needed because sorting and filtering. Model doesn't know anything about View. So as you are trying to access model index via view index you have to convert it. 
 From [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)

> Similarly when using the sorting and filtering functionality provided
>   by RowSorter **the underlying TableModel does not need to know how to do
>   sorting, rather RowSorter will handle it. Coordinate conversions will
>   be necessary when using the row based methods of JTable with the
>   underlying TableModel**. **All of JTables row based methods are in terms
>   of the RowSorter, which is not necessarily the same as that of the
>   underlying TableModel**. For example, **the selection is always in terms
>   of JTable so that when using RowSorter you will need to convert using
>   convertRowIndexToView or convertRowIndexToModel**.

More information:

[convertRowIndexToView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToView%28int%29)

[convertRowIndexToModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel%28int%29)

**UPDATE**

*Why "correct"?*

As @camickr pointed , this also applies to columns. Cause columns can swap. So you need to use

[convertColumnIndexToView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToModel%28int%29)

[convertColumnIndexToModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToView%28int%29)

Comment: @sajjid, In the spirit of the question this answer is reasonable, but it is not complete. Given that this answer assumes the potential that the table is sorted or filtered, the answer should also assume that the TableColumns can be reorder, in which case it is not appropriate to hardcode the columns value for retrieving the ID value. See my complete solution.